# Prevent PageView.builder from swiping past to the max page

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to test the PageView.builder found in this package: smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.1

PageView

```
                child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: controller,
                  // itemCount: pages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return pages[index % pages.length];
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Pages

```
    final pages = List.generate(
        6,
        (index) => Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 4),
              child: Container(
                height: 280,
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                  "Page $index",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),
                )),
              ),
            ));
```

Controller

```
final controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8, keepPage: true);
```

Scrolling to left will be disabled if the fist page.
But I want to try to disable the scrolling once I reach the max page. How will I achieve that?

Comment: Add Some Code for better underStand  What you Exactly want

Comment: I added the codes

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1__K9tjHTD12loTm5zESDT1vGBHNJGQFL/view you want like this

Comment: Yes, I tried to find a parameter to do that but I haven't found any.

Comment: kindly add image or video

Comment: Where did you find that video? Does it have a source code for me to check?

Comment: i will added code check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i'm Try to Solve your Problem :**

**Here is The Code:**

```
 import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<String> dataList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];

int pointer = 0;

class Swipefunctions extends StatefulWidget {
  const Swipefunctions({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Swipefunctions> createState() => _SwipefunctionsState();
}

class _SwipefunctionsState extends State<Swipefunctions> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("THIS IS APPBAR"),
        ),
        body: PageView.builder(
            onPageChanged: (int index) {
              print("prinetd");
              setState(() {
              pointer++;
              pointer=index;
              });
            },
            itemCount: dataList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return MyPage(index: index,);
            })
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const MyPage({super.key, required this.index});

  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("pointer at $pointer");
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(dataList[pointer], style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't disable after I swipe at the end of the pages. Also, I'm expecting that at least the variable pointer must have a comparison in dataList.length for it to work. Anyway, it would seem to me that there is no parameter to quickly disable the scrolling after the last page.